# Any way to mimic coalesce in a unique index for a h2 database?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, h2, lombok

I am trying to create a unique index with two databases: postgres and h2. The unique index looks something like this:

`create unique index idx_unique on table(foo, bar, coalesce(unique, ''));`

However, this works in postgres, as I believe it allows functions to be used in a unique index, but does not work for the h2 database. I was wondering if there was anything I could do to work around this?

I also tried using @ColumnDefault in the entity class on the unique attribute:

```
@ColumnDefault("")
private String unique;
```

However, I am using lombok getters and setters, and I think it is ignoring it (I may be wrong, but either way it doesnt seem to be applying the annotation)

My end goal is to make the unique index differentiate entities that have the optional unique attribute set to null, but I previously discovered that postgres treats nulls as not equal.

Let me know if there's any clarification or further information that needs to be provided.

Comment: About Lombok: you can put annotations on generated getters and setters: https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter but it won't help, because the `@ColumnDefault` is only used when the column value is not given during insert.

Comment: I suspect you are asking for H2 because you want to use it for testing. Don't use TestContainers and use your actual production database product. https://www.testcontainers.org/